# File upload - no link

Tags: php, file-upload

whether someone is willing to help me with the code for file upload?

With this code when you add a file, the table to get an overview of just the file name without a link to view

What are we missing?

thank you

```
add.php

<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["submit"])) {
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(ime, prezime, email, adresa, grad, file) VALUES('".$_POST["ime"]."','".$_POST["prezime"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["adresa"]."','".$_POST["grad"]."','".$_POST["file"]."')");
if(!$result){
$message="Problem in Adding to database. Please Retry.";
} else {
header("Location:index.php");
}
}
?>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function validate() {
var valid = true;
$(".demoInputBox").css('background-color','');
$(".info").html('');

if(!$("#ime").val()) {
$("#ime-info").html("(required)");
$("#ime").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
if(!$("#prezime").val()) {
$("#prezime-info").html("(required)");
$("#prezime").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
if(!$("#email").val()) {
$("#email-info").html("(required)");
$("#email").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
if(!$("#adresa").val()) {
$("#adresa-info").html("(required)");
$("#adresa").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
if(!$("#grad").val()) {
$("#grad-info").html("(required)");
$("#grad").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
if(!$("#file").val()) {
$("#file-info").html("(required)");
$("#file").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
valid = false;
}
return valid;
}
</script>
<form name="frmToy" method="post" action="" id="frmToy" onClick="return validate();">
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<div>
<label style="padding-top:20px;">Ime</label>
<span id="ime-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Prezime</label>
<span id="prezime-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>E-mail</label>
<span id="email-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Adresa</label>
<span id="adresa-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="adresa" id="adresa" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>Grad</label>
<span id="grad-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="grad" id="grad" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<label>File (pdf, doc, docx, xcl, xclx, jpg, png, gif)</label>
<span id="file-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnAddAction" value="Add" />
</div>



index.php

<?php
foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
if(is_numeric($k)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["datum_prijave"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["ime"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["prezime"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["email"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["adresa"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["grad"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[$k]["file"]; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
}
if(isset($result["perpage"])) {
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align=right> <?php echo $result["perpage"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know modern version
Can you  help me with this version?

Comment: There are a bunch of links in my previous comment. Click on them.

Comment: I do not know php
because I seek help

thanks